# React Native - Can't increase width of Button in row

Tags: android, react-native

I tried both absolute and flex dimensions, the View just sets the Button at standard dimensions (approx 50px). The height is stretched, but the width can't possibly change.

```
class Calculator extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { "lastClicked" : "None" };
        this.buttonPress = this.buttonPress.bind(this);
    }
    createButton(id) {
        return (
            <Button
                title={id}
                onPress={() => this.buttonPress(id)}
            />
        );
    }
    buttonPress(id) {
        this.setState({ "lastClicked" : id });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{alignContent: "stretch"}}>
                <View style={{width: 500}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>This is a JavaScript Calculator</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>You clicked: {this.state.lastClicked}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{width: 500}}>
                    <View style={{ width: 500, height: 150, flexDirection : "row", alignItems: "stretch", alignContent: "stretch", alignSelf: "stretch"}}>
                        {this.createButton("4")}
                        {this.createButton("5")}
                        {this.createButton("6")}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ width: 500, height: 150, flexDirection : "row", alignItems: "stretch", alignContent: "stretch", alignSelf: "stretch"}}>
                        {this.createButton("4")}
                        {this.createButton("5")}
                        {this.createButton("6")}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ width: 500, height: 150, flexDirection : "row", alignItems: "stretch", alignContent: "stretch", alignSelf: "stretch"}}>
                        {this.createButton("1")}
                        {this.createButton("2")}
                        {this.createButton("3")}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

}

Can you see the issue? I am new to React-Native and the issue already consumed 3 hours of my life.

Comment: What kind of layout of buttons are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a 3x3 grid as a common calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `createButton()` method with something like that:

```
createButton(id) {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => this.buttonPress(id)}>
       <View style={{flex: 3, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:30}}>{id}</Text>
       </View>
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

I wrapped a `<View>` with style `flex: 3` for setting the width to a third of the screen size. `flexDirection:'column'` and `justifyContent:'center'` will center the number in the middle of the `View`. The `View` is wrapped in a [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html) so that we can bind the `onPress` event.

For your grid of numbers, you wrapped then in `<View style={{width: 500}}>`. This is not always the size of the screen. It's easy to get the screen width using [`Dimensions`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html).

At the start of your file, you can declare something like:

```
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window');
```

And then replace `<View style={{width: 500}}>` by `<View style={{width: screenWidth}}>`.

Overall, your new code should look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { "lastClicked" : "None" };
        this.buttonPress = this.buttonPress.bind(this);
    }
    createButton(id) {
        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => this.buttonPress(id)}>
           <View style={{flex: 3, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30}}>{id}</Text>
           </View>
           </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
    buttonPress(id) {
        this.setState({ "lastClicked" : id });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{alignContent: "stretch"}}>
                <View style={{width: screenWidth}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>This is a JavaScript Calculator</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>You clicked: {this.state.lastClicked}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{width:screenWidth}}>
                    <View style={{height: 150, flexDirection : "row", alignItems: "stretch", alignContent: "stretch", alignSelf: "stretch",}}>
                        {this.createButton("7")}
                        {this.createButton("8")}
                        {this.createButton("9")}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{height: 150, flexDirection : "row", alignItems: "stretch", alignContent: "stretch", alignSelf: "stretch"}}>
                        {this.createButton("4")}
                        {this.createButton("5")}
                        {this.createButton("6")}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{height: 150, flexDirection : "row", alignItems: "stretch", alignContent: "stretch", alignSelf: "stretch"}}>
                        {this.createButton("1")}
                        {this.createButton("2")}
                        {this.createButton("3")}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[Demo on `snack.expo.io`](https://snack.expo.io/SkVyQipAe)

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked! I understand now that my error was trying to style the Button component which apparently doesn't have a style prop. Is that correct?